# Interface translation conflict / same EN word, different translations

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've created a custom module, that uses templates with hard coded strings. I've created the `.pot` and `.po` files and included them my module's YML file. The Twig tempatles translate those strings using the `|t` operator. This works fine.

Now I've run into a problem: My module offers button to `book` an accommodation, which clashes with Drupal's `book` (to read) module. In the german translation those two words are completely different.

I've got two questions:

1. How to I provide a translation for the `book` verb in my module, in a way that it doesn't clash with the book module.
2. How to I use the tell Twig to use the correct `book` string from my module?

E.g. this template code
`First I want to {{ 'book'|t('context_accomodation') }} a hotel room and when I arrive I want to read a {{ 'book'|t('context_reading') }}`

should render in english
*First I want to `book` a hotel room and when I arrive I want to read a `book`*

and should render in german
*First I want to `buchen` a hotel room and when I arrive I want to read a `Buch`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal does have an answer to this problem, at least if it's your own code where you need to make that distinction. It's called context.

In the PO file, add a `msgctxt` line

```
# an explanatory comment line for your translator
msgctxt "Accomodation"
msgid "book"
msgstr "buchen"
```

In PHP, it works like this:

```
<?php
t('book', [], ['context' => 'Accomodation']);
?>
```

In twig, it should go like this:

```
{{ 'book'|t({}, {'context': 'Accomodation'}) }}
```

The problem with this approach is that the developer needs to be aware that a certain word might have a multiple context specific translations in another language that he most likely doesn't know. But for your specific scenario, it should work fine.

Comment: Google told me there is a msgctext for PO files e.g. `msgctxt "Accodmodation"` , I guess Drupal/Twig will be using this. Need to test when back in office.